# How to generate XSD for JaxB Java files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, intellij-idea

Is there an easy way to do this. I have some classes annotated with

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

I am trying to lookup at the same time on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a way to do this in IntelliJ, then it is easy to do using the JAXB runtime APIs:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
```

And

```
private class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        return result;
    }

}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

Answer (score 0):

You can use [schemagen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/schemagen.html)